# How to make the dimension of a button relative to the screen size?

Tags: android

How can I make the width of a button so that it is, for example, a quater of the screen, or a fifth?

Answer (score 0):

Take the width of the screen and divide it by **2** (so you have the half of the screen width) and then again by **2** to get the quarter of the screen width:

```
button_width = (screen_width/4)
```

Comment: Multiplications are faster than divisions. So multiplying by the inverse is faster. I.e.: multiplying by 1/4 is the same a dividing by 4, bust faster. So go for `screen_width * 0.25`. If the multiplication or division is by a power of 2 (i.e.: 4), you can use an even faster technique: Bit Shifting (left to multiply, right to divide). Therefore, you'd better go for `screen_width >> 2 `(2, because 2^2 = 4).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ConstraintLayout` as your parent and add your view as a child with the width `0dp` and set your `app:layout_constraintWidth_percent` to your desired percent.

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:id="@+id/activity_main_inference"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">


<View
    android:id="@+id/viewTop"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintWidth_default="percent"
    app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.5" />
 </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `ConstraintLayout` and set a vertical `Guideline`, below is an example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.25"
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```